# Change readout size python widgets

Tags: python, widget, size

[IM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRTMz.png)

As you all can the the readout does not show all the numbers correctly. How can this be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `layout` setting:

```py
widgets.FloatRangeSlider({
  ...
  layout={'width': '400px'}
})
```